# Github matrix included configuration turns string variable into an array

Tags: github-actions

[image]

### Background

I have a number of different repos in my monorepo project.

For my `api` and `common-services` repo, i want to run a `test` command

For my `frontend` repo, I want to run a `test2` command

### Current

Currently, when running the test command for the `frontend` repo, the `command` variable is provided in the job as an `Array`.

### Expected

I expect the `command` variable to always be a string

---

Note: I have simplified my test workflow to represent the problem. I do not want to manually specify every test configuration as an include.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I was confusing the array input of the original matrix with the includes configuration ...

### wrong

```yaml
      matrix:
        repo: [api, common-services]
        command: [test]
        include:
          - repo: frontend
            command: [test2]
          - repo: common-lib
            command: [test2]
```

### correct

```yaml
      matrix:
        repo: [api, common-services]
        command: [test]
        include:
          - repo: frontend
            command: test2 # DO NOT SPECIFY AS ARRAY HERE
          - repo: common-lib
            command: test2 # DO NOT SPECIFY AS ARRAY HERE
```